# Syncing to a Box file via CARTO

Tags: carto, csv, import

So I'm pretty sure I'm missing something very simple, but --

I'm trying to create a new dataset inside CARTO, by using the "Connect Dataset" button and choosing "Box" (I want to connect to a CSV file inside my Box account). Basically the exact workflow described [here](https://carto.com/docs/carto-editor/datasets/#connect-dataset) in the "Connect Dataset" section.

Unfortunately the list of files I get to choose from in Box doesn't seem to include my file? The interface says it's displaying 200 files -- a round number like that makes me suspect there's some kind of limit to how many files can be read from Box & it's somehow arbitrarily picking which ones it's making available to me? I have way more than 200 files in my Box account. The "Search" function doesn't seem to work at all, as it turns up no results for anything, no matter what I search for.

I went through this process perfectly once before, but now the list simply doesn't include the file I need to import/sync to -- though it's an accepted format. How can I make the CARTO import mechanism via Box see the CSV file I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. CARTO's Box connector shows a maximum of 200 files. You can check the source code [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/blob/master/services/datasources/lib/datasources/url/box.rb#L387). There is a couple of fixes requested that could solve this issue:

- [a Chooser/Picker](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/13259),
- [show the most recent files](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/14118).

Hopefully, one of these will be addressed soon.

**Disclaimer**: I work at CARTO.